# how does this javascript "translate" to coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

JS:

```
func(a, 'b', function(e, obj) {
    //does some stuff
}.another_func(obj));
```

My Coffee:

```
func(a, 'b', (e, obj) ->
   #does some stuff
.another_func(obj)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Check yourself](http://js2coffee.org/)

Comment: @zishe thank you very much for the link to js2coffee - I didn't know this tool, I appreciate. However, don't understand the downvotes. It's a valid question, and I didn't know the tool. There's no need for that step, instead you taught me the tool and that's great. You could have provided that as an answer and I would accept that instead. There are soooo many stupid questions about jquery etc. in stackoverflow which have 1k + votes, where the asker could just look at the docs as well. I think ppl are using downvotes in a wrong manner.

Comment: You should first try google there are bunch of results by "convert js to coffee" query.

Comment: Is this even real code? Are you extending `Function`'s `prototype`?

Comment: you're right @zishe I should. As I am freelancing, sometimes I am asking stackoverflow too quickly. It just feels like having a lot of co-workers...

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the function in explicit parenthesis:

```
func a, "b", ((e, obj) ->
    #does some stuff
).another_func obj
```

(or, with explicit method invocation):

```
func(a, "b", ((e, obj) ->
    #does some stuff
).another_func(obj))
```